# Google analytics filters - find and replace multiple instances of an _

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

I'm trying to do a find and replace filter on a google analytics view but I'm not having much luck. It seems a relatively simple filter but it only seems to partially work.

I have a bunch of campaign names for the same campaign coming through like "campaign sem_1", "campaign_sem_1", "campaign_sem 1". What I'm trying to do is consolidate all of them by doing a search and replace on the _ and replace them with a space.

[Example filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEodg.png)

When I verify this filter it only seems to replace the first instance of an underscore in the campaign name rather than all instances of the underscores. So in an example like "Campaign_sem_1" the result would be "Campaign sem_1"

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'd have to apply the filter multiple times, that would work if you know the maximum number of underscores.

Comment: An alternative, if the  number of underscores in known before, is to use an advanced filter to extract all the bits that are not underscores via regex and reassemble them in the output field with a different separator (in that case presumably a whitespace).

Comment: Is there any way of performing a count of underscores and removing them. I won't know a number for every campaign. It's a safe assumption there won't be more than 5 though so worst case I could just add five seperate filters but it seems inelegant. I wonder if there's another approach to normalise campaigns.